# git merge files from another branch

Tags: git, merge, branch

I need to merge files from another branch into my master branch. The clue: The files have changes on both branches. Lets assume that we have the `master` and the branch `other`. Content is changed on `other` and sometimes added. On `master` there is only added content that is not in `other` and no changes to the existing content.

I tried to create a patch file from the branch `other` that I can apply it in `master`, the problem is that this patch will discard all added content done in `master`.

Is there a way to merge `other` into `master` for specific files only without discarding (if there is a conflict I could resolve it with `git mergetool`).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's wrong with just `git merge other`? You might get merge conflicts and you can resolve them.

Comment: Because there are several other changes i do not want in my master.

Comment: Cherry pick the commits you want then? From `other` to `master`.

Comment: There are also other files in the commit that I do not want and the changes are scattered among several commits

Comment: Cherry pick each relevant commit with the `-n`  flag so that local commits are not made. Then edit the patch and when you're satisfied, do a commit.

Comment: To add on editing the patch: `git add -p` might be of help.

Comment: `git add -p` works but it's a horrible UI. Several git clients  provide a much better interface.